# Webpack style-loader modules are overriding installed component css

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, redux

I am using the [react-super-select](https://github.com/alsoscotland/react-super-select) component in a react/redux project that I'm working on.

That project currently uses webpack and style-loader to load my styling:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const poststylus = require('poststylus');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
        './src/client/index',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/static/',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['babel'],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.styl$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules!stylus-loader',
        }],
    },
    stylus: {
        use: [
            poststylus([ 'autoprefixer', 'rucksack-css' ]),
        ],
    },
};
```

I am finding that this use of style-loader seems to be overriding the styling provided with react-super-select.

Is there a way to configure webpack so that it does not override the style for this component?

Comment: The order of which the styles are loaded depends on the order the modules are imported. That's what the documentation says.

Comment: How does this answer my question? Are you suggesting that I put some kind of 'css' loader at the end of the `module.loaders` array? If so, how do I structure this. Telling me to RTFM in this context isn't very helpful.

Comment: What I mean to say is that you cannot impact the order in which the styles are loaded (so the answer would be no). However, if you can separate the conflicting modules into separate bundles, you could use the [text extraction plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin), to extract the CSS into separate files and include the files in your HTML document in the correct order yourself.

Comment: Looks like this might present one approach: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/215. Is it the case that my css-loader is loading all CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to do this -- I created a wrapper component that loaded the css explicitly:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import ReactSuperSelect from 'react-super-select';
import 'react-super-select/lib/react-super-select.css';


export default class Dropdown extends Component {

  render() {
      const { options, onChange, ...preferences } = this.props;
      return (
        <ReactSuperSelect placeholder={preferences.placeholder}
                  dataSource={options}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  searchable={preferences.searchable} />
      );
  }
}

Dropdown.propTypes = {
    options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    preferences: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

and then I added a line to load css in my webpack config:

```
module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['babel'],
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
            test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'file',
        },
        {
            test: /\.styl$/,
            loader: 'style!css?modules!stylus',
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style!css',
        }],
    },
```